# Excel VBA Auto Filter and Delete filtered rows

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I'm trying to copy data from on worksheet into another, filter data and delete filtered rows and keep unfiltered rows. Running into runtime error at *rng.EntireRow.Delete* 1004 AutoFilter method of range class failed, while trying to execute the following code. Can you please help me resolve the issue.

Code:

```
Public Sub listAccounts()

     Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy Destination:=Sheets("listAccounts").range("A1")

     Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, LstRw As Long

     Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("listAccounts")
     
     ws.range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:=Array("1", "2", "A"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
     ws.range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:=Array("X", "Y", "Z"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

     ws.Activate

    With ws
        LstRw = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        Set rng = .Range("A2:A" & LstRw).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        rng.EntireRow.Delete
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Might be better to focus your question one piece of code and indicate exactly which line causes the error.

Answer (score 1):

### Delete Filtered Rows (`AutoFilter`)

```vb
Sub ListAccounts()

    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containing this code
    
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Sheets("ListAccounts")
    
    wb.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells.Copy ws.Range("A1")
    
    If ws.FilterMode Then ws.ShowAllData
    If ws.AutoFilterMode Then ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    ' Reference the range (has headers).
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    
    ' Reference the data range (no headers).
    If rg.Rows.Count = 1 Then Exit Sub ' no data
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = rg.Resize(rg.Rows.Count - 1).Offset(1)
    
    rg.AutoFilter 4, Array("1", "2", "A"), xlFilterValues ' note 'rg'
    rg.AutoFilter 6, Array("X", "Y", "Z"), xlFilterValues ' note 'rg'
    
    ' Attempt to reference the visible range (the filtered rows).
    Dim vrg As Range
    On Error Resume Next
        Set vrg = drg.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) ' note 'drg'
    On Error GoTo 0
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If vrg Is Nothing Then Exit Sub ' no filtered rows
    
    vrg.Delete xlShiftUp ' no need to delete entire rows
    
    MsgBox "Accounts listed.", vbInformation
     
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried your code but encountering error at line "vr.Delete xlShiftUp". Run-time error '1004'. Can't move cells in a filtered range or table.